# Angular Unit Test : No pending request to flush

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am new to Karma so this might sound trivial. I have the following route structure in place.

```
  angular
        .module('appRouter',['ui.router'])
        .config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
            $stateProvider
                .state('settings.profile',{
                    url:'/profile',
                    templateUrl:'templates/profile.html'
                })
                .state('settings.account',{
                    url:'/account',
                    templateUrl:'templates/account.html',
                    controller:function(resolveData){
                        console.log(resolveData);
                    },
                    resolve:{
                        resolveData : function($http){
                            var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
                            return $http.get(root+'/posts/1').then(function(response){

                                return response.data;
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/settings/profile');
```

**Now the unit test for it looks like below. Please note I am trying to test resolve functionality also**

```
describe('UI Routerer Config For Account',function(){
    var $state,$rootScope,$injector,$httpBackend,state = "settings.account";

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('appRouter');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_,_$injector_,_$state_,_$httpBackend_,$templateCache){
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $state = _$state_;
        $injector = _$injector_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $templateCache.put('templates/account.html','');
    }));

    it('should resolve "resolveData"',function(){
        const state = $state.get('settings.account');
        const resolveFn = state.resolve.resolveData;

        $httpBackend.when('GET','https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').respond(200,{
           "userId": 1,
            "id": 1,
            "title": "...",
            "body": "..."       
        });
        $httpBackend.expectGET('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
        $httpBackend.flush();

        const responseData = {
            "userId": 1,
            "id": 1,
            "title": "...",
            "body": "..."
        };

        expect(resolveData).toEqual(responseData);
    });

});
```

**But this fails** :

```
 should resolve "resolveData"
     UI Routerer Config For Account
     Error: No pending request to flush !
    at Function.$httpBackend.flush (bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1816:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (test/controllers/main-controller-spec.js:97:22)
```

What am I doing wrong ? Please explain.

Comment: I'll guess and suggest the problem is that you're not invoking the function `state.resolve.resolveData`. You should try invoking it between `expectGET` and `flush`.